# Generating text file based on two tables - R

Tags: r, ptv-vissim

I am trying to create a text file based on two tables.
The text file should look like this for each interstage:

```
$INTERSTAGE
ISt name               : St1->St12
ISt description        : Source: Stage sequence plan
ISt Description: 
INTERSTAGE_number      : 1
Length [s]             : 0
From stage             : 1
To stage               : 12
$
SG3   -127    "insert value later manually".
```

If a SG goes from an active phase to an inactive phase it should be  written down as f.i.

```
SG3  -127  "insert value later manually"
```

If a SG goes from an inactive phase to an active phase it should be written down as f.i.

```
SG3   "insert value later manually"   127
```

I tried to program this in R. But it does not work when i have for instance a phase12 instead of a phase3.
How can i solve this issue?

```
tabel_signal_groups <- data.frame(
  Signal_Group = c("SG1", "SG2", "SG3", "SG4"),
  phase1 = c("x", "", "x","x"),
  phase2 = c("", "x", "","x"),
  phase12 = c("", "", "","x")
)

tabel <- data.frame(
  Interstage = c("ISt112", "ISt23", "ISt31"),
  from_stage = c(1, 2, 3),
  to_stage = c(12, 3, 1),
  length = c(0, 5, 7)
)


# Aangenomen voorbeeldkleuren voor rood en groen
red_color <- "Red"
green_color <- "Green"

# Functie om de tekststring te genereren voor elke record in de tabel
genereer_text_string <- function(row, signal_groups_df) {
  text_string <- paste0(
    "$", row["Interstage"], "\n",
    "ISt name               : St", row["from_stage"], "->St", row["to_stage"], "\n",
    "ISt description        : Source: Stage sequence plan\n",
    "ISt Description: \n",
    "INTERSTAGE_number      : ", row["Interstage"], "\n",
    "Length [s]             : ", row["length"], "\n",
    "From stage             : ", row["from_stage"], "\n",
    "To stage               : ", row["to_stage"], "\n"
  )
  
  # Check welke signal groups actief zijn in elke fase en voeg rood/groen informatie toe
  for (i in seq_along(signal_groups_df$Signal_Group)) {
    signal_group <- signal_groups_df$Signal_Group[i]
    active_phases <- colnames(signal_groups_df)[signal_groups_df[i, ] == "x"]
    
    if (length(active_phases) > 0) {
      if (all(grepl("phase1|phase2", active_phases))) {
        # Add information for red signal group
        text_string <- paste0(text_string, signal_group, "          -127          Handmatig Invullen\n")
      } else {
        # Add information for green signal group
        text_string <- paste0(text_string, signal_group, "          Handmatig Invullen          127\n")
      }
    }
  }
  
  text_string <- paste0(text_string, "$\n")
  return(text_string)
}

# Loop over de rijen van de tabel en creëer de tekststring voor elke rij
alle_text_strings <- apply(tabel, 1, genereer_text_string, signal_groups_df = tabel_signal_groups)

# Resultaten afdrukken
cat(alle_text_strings)
```

Comment: use `cat` instead of `paste`

Comment: This has nothing to do with Vissim? Why the Vissim tag?

Comment: The PUA files contains the data about the interstages. This datafile is loaded into vissim.